# Run mpi job from bash script, batch mode

Tags: bash, mpich

I am trying to build a script that runs mpi jobs in batch mode at certain hours. If I run in a console `mpdallexit`, `mpdboot` and `mpirun` everything works fine and the parallel jobs start on all nodes in mpd.hosts. But if I try to run from a bash script (sent with at script now +1 minute) the mpd crashes and no jobs are started.

This are the relevant lines in the script

```
$path_mpi/mpdallexit 
$path_mpi/mpdboot -n 5 &
time $path_mpi/mpirun -n 21 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu 
$path_mpi/mpdallexit
```

and the error messages from log

```
mpiexec_ventus: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_meteo); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
In case 1, you can start an mpd on this host with:
    mpd &
and you will be able to run jobs just on this host.
For more details on starting mpds on a set of hosts, see
the MPICH2 Installation Guide.
```

I have tried different options from mpdboot

```
--loccons says you do not want a console available on local mpd(s)
--remcons says you do not want consoles available on remote mpd(s)
```

or

```
mpdboot -n 5 &
```

but without success

Mpich installed at /usr/local/mpich2-1.0.5p4/

**EDIT 1:**

After trying @shellter advice on sleep I couldn't run the parallel jobs nor with `at` neither `cron`. When issuing a batch `mpirun` job some processes start on the master node but not in the other cluster nodes:

In the master node

> ```
> ps -ef | grep rams
> meteo    28043 26837  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 time /usr/bin/mpirun -n 50 -f machinefile ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28044 28043  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/mpirun -n 50 -f machinefile ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28050 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28051 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28052 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28053 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28054 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28055 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28056 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28057 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28058 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28059 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28060 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> meteo    28061 28045  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 ./rams60 -f RAMSIN.operatiu
> ```

Besides, no output files are created by rams60 while the first thing it does is to write start analysis files.

Everything runs fine if I execute the script in the command line but it seems that mpich can not communicate with the nodes when in batch.

At first I installed mpich2 in the master node and NFS exported to the other nodes. Now I have installed mpich2 in every node.

Thanks

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe the mpdboot needs a few seconds of `sleep` separating it from the following cmd? Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter Finally I have tried to build a function in my script that checks mpd (mpdtrace output) at the start of the script. If check fails then I use `sleep 10` between `mpdboot` and `mpdtrace`. This seems to work when running the script from the command line, I'll try with cron and let you know. Thanks

Comment: No way, launching with `at` does not work.

Comment: Sorry, but "does not work" doesn't give us much to work with. Do you have evidence that any of you `mpd` programs get started, or are you seeing err msgs like `pdm: command not found` (or similar). Consider editing your question with this information, so anyone can help. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter With "does not work" I meant "no changes". But you are right, more information on my side will help people help me. I edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could resolve the issue with cron job thanks to Gilles Goullardet in the "mpich-discuss" mailing list.

The problem came from the environment in which batch jobs are run. Cron uses a minimal enviroment so some libs needed for my job were not found in the cluster nodes. I've had to add a line to my script exporting some libs:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mpich2-1.0.5p4/lib:/usr/local/hdf5/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Now everything is working fine and my script runs twice a day as desired. Thank you all for your help, in the process I've learned some thins about cron.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear:

```
mpiexec_ventus: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_meteo); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
```

I assume you have mpd running so... check its `-n` option.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. That error comes, I think from first mpdallexit. Then I issue `mpdboot -n 5 &` and `mpirun -n 21 command`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that software but.. as it's written you should have `mpd` running. The question is do you have one or not (I assume you do) and is it running with `-n` or without. If it's not visible with `ps` than try to `cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline`

Answer (score 1):

You can use screen to give your script a tty since cron, at or a nested script doesn't allocate one by default. This way you can attach to it if necessary.

```
screen -D -m <command>
```

This will launch your command in a detached screen session that will exit when the command finishes.

Comment: How should I use `screen`? `screen -D -m myscript` or inside my script `screen -D -m mpirun...`? Thanks for answering.